# I want help to finish the tree diagram

Tags: tikz-trees

[image]Question: I have been trying to complete the tree diagram which I started (see the figure).

Please help.[image]

This is what I have

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[level 1/.style={sibling distance=5cm},level 2/.style={sibling distance=4.0cm}]
        \node {1}[edge from parent fork down]
        child { node {2}}
        child { node {3}
            child {node{4} }
            child {node{5}}
        }               
        ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since the length of the nodes' content and the width of your text block are apparently crucial (judging from your comments on answers), your MWE should reflect this.

Answer (score 6):

For comparison, here is how you could do this using `forest`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={forked edge, edge=->, draw, circle, minimum size=8mm, l sep=5mm}
[1, s sep=5cm
    [2]
    [3, s sep=4cm
        [4, s sep=3cm
            [6, s sep=1cm
                [9][10][11]
            ]
            [7]
            [8, s sep=2cm
                [12][13]
            ]
        ]
        [5]
    ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you but when I replace 4 by any large text , circle becomes very big. Any solution for this issue.

Comment: You can remove `circle` to get rectangular nodes that may fit better. You can also remove `draw` if you don't want the node borders drawn at all.

Comment: Please look the image what I get after correcting your codes. Do the needful. It will be great help to me.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. What change are you trying to make from your image?

Comment: My figure not properly fit in the page and second how to increase vertical distance

Comment: `l sep` controls spacing between levels. Increase `l sep=5mm`. If the figure is too wide, reduce `s sep` (sibling separation).

Comment: Can you edit your answer? Please

Answer (score 5):

You just have to nest your `child`s:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
  
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[level 1/.style={sibling distance=5cm},
      level 2/.style={sibling distance=4.0cm},
      level 3/.style={sibling distance=2.0cm},
      level 4/.style={sibling distance=1.0cm}]
      \node {1}[edge from parent fork down]
      child { node {2}}
      child { node {3}
        child {node{4}
          child {node{6}
            child {node{9}}
            child {node{10}}
            child {node{11}}}
          child {node{7}}
          child {node{8}
            child {node{12}}
            child {node{13}}}}
        child {node{5}}
      }               
      ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
  
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you do want encircled numbers, in the `tikzpicture`'s options add

```
every node/.style={draw, circle},
```

Answer (score 1):

This is based on Sandy G's answer. I have no idea whether you are using A4 or US letter. Likely the latter, but I assume the former as it is narrower.

If you use `forest`, something a bit like your tree fits. It isn't quite your tree because I lost patience typing contents when the words became unfamiliar and started making stuff up instead.

Note that the reason switching to `forest` helps is that the package produces more compact trees by default (`fit=tight`).

```
\begin{forest}
  % ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/707154/ addaswyd o ateb Sandy G: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/706800/
  forked edges,
  for tree={
    edge+=->,
    draw,
    font=\sffamily,
  },
  where={>Ow+P{n children}{isodd(#1)}}{%
    delay={for n=2{calign with current edge}}
  }{},
  [Fluids
    [Ideal Fluids]
    [Real Fluids
      [Non-Newtonian Fluids
        [Time-Independant Fluids
          [Vouch-saving Vanilla][Soliciting Sourdough][Advocating Avocado]
        ]
        [Timeless Thyme]
        [Time-Dependant Fluids
          [Peppermint][Spearmint]
        ]
      ]
      [Newtonian Fluids]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

[image: forest version]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/707154/ addaswyd o ateb Sandy G: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/706800/
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{forest}
  % ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/707154/ addaswyd o ateb Sandy G: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/706800/
  forked edges,
  for tree={
    edge+=->,
    draw,
    font=\sffamily,
  },
  where={>Ow+P{n children}{isodd(#1)}}{%
    delay={for n=2{calign with current edge}}
  }{},
  [Fluids
    [Ideal Fluids]
    [Real Fluids
      [Non-Newtonian Fluids
        [Time-Independant Fluids
          [Vouch-saving Vanilla][Soliciting Sourdough][Advocating Avocado]
        ]
        [Timeless Thyme]
        [Time-Dependant Fluids
          [Peppermint][Spearmint]
        ]
      ]
      [Newtonian Fluids]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

If that's not sufficient, I suggest either using `sidewaysfigure` from the `rotating` package or allowing line-breaks in nodes.

```
\begin{forest}
  % ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/707154/ addaswyd o ateb Sandy G: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/706800/
  forked edges,
  for tree={
    edge+=->,
    draw,
    font=\sffamily,
    align=center,
  },
  where={>Ow+P{n children}{isodd(#1)}}{%
    delay={for n=2{calign with current edge}}
  }{},
  [Fluids
    [Ideal Fluids]
    [Real Fluids
      [Non-Newtonian Fluids
        [Time-Independant\\Fluids
          [Vouch-saving\\Vanilla][Soliciting\\Sourdough][Advocating\\Avocado]
        ]
        [Timeless\\Thyme]
        [Time-Dependant\\Fluids
          [Peppermint][Spearmint]
        ]
      ]
      [Newtonian Fluids]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

[image: with multiline nodes]

Better yet, avoid duplicating information. The top of the tree says these are all fluids, so why keep repeating yourself? Removing excess `Fluids` may make your diagram clearer, even if it doesn't reduce the width much.

Or, if you want to be more adventurous, you can even turn recalcitrant nodes, though I would only suggest using this method in appropriate cases (and I doubt this is among them).

```
\begin{forest}
  % ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/707154/ addaswyd o ateb Sandy G: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/706800/
  forked edges,
  for tree={
    edge+=->,
    draw,
    font=\sffamily,
  },
  where={>Ow+P{n children}{isodd(#1)}}{%
    delay={for n=2{calign with current edge}}
  }{},
  before typesetting nodes={%
    tempcounta/.max={>O{level}}{tree},
    where={> OR= {level}{tempcounta}}{rotate=-90,anchor=parent}{},
  },
  [Fluids
    [Ideal]
    [Real
      [Non-Newtonian
        [Time-Independent
          [Vouch-saving Vanilla][Soliciting Sourdough][Advocating Avocado]
        ]
        [Timeless Thyme]
        [Time-Dependant
          [Peppermint][Spearmint]
        ]
      ]
      [Newtonian]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

[image: turned final level and fewer fluids]

Comment: Thank you so much for your innovative answer.